# Hibernate per-user database

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I am currently working on a (website-)project in which I intent to keep each user's data separate from another. The main database (containing information about the user (user, password etc)) is a MySQL database.

Per-user there is a lot of data that needs to be stored and is important not to mix up with another user his/her data. Now I was thinking of using a sqlite db per user but I found out Hibernate (the db framework of my choice) does support sqlite by default.

I found http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/ as an option. But I was wondering if there are any other database types with which it is easy to create one per-user, and preferably compatible with hibernate? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check out [Multi-tenancy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html)  in hibernate